# Add to or edit a gem without editing the gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, methods, rubygems, associations

I am using the PublicActivity gem to create a news feed.
Ive already got it up and running fine, but I want my activity to associate with another table to show more details

Currently my news feed just says "Posted a Micropost" when someone makes a post
I want the news feed to display the MicroPost that was posted.
I edited the gem file to include an association so that the activity looks in the microposts table to get the micropost

```
module PublicActivity
 module ORM
  module ActiveRecord
   # The ActiveRecord model containing
   # details about recorded activity.
   class Activity < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    include Renderable
    belongs_to :trackable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :recipient, :polymorphic => true
    serialize :parameters, Hash

    # I added this
    has_one :micropost, foreign_key: "id", primary_key: "trackable_id"
    end
  end
 end
end
```

This seems to do the trick and shows the micropost that the user posted except I want to do this without editing the gem. I tried many different ways of monkey patching it but just cant seem to figure it out. Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Here is some of my code

controller

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: [current_user.followed_user_ids, current_user], owner_type: "User")
 end
end
```

view

```
<h1>Activities</h1>

<% @activities.each do |activity| if activity.trackable %>
 <div class="activity">
  <%= render_activity activity %>
 </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

micropost activity

```
<% if activity.trackable %> 
<%= link_to gravatar_for(activity.owner), activity.owner %>
<span class="user">
    <%= link_to activity.owner.name, activity.owner %>
</span>
<span class="content">
    Created a Micropost
    # <%= activity.micropost.content %> COMMENTED OUT WHILE NOT WORKING
</span>
<span class="timestamp">
    <%= time_ago_in_words(activity.created_at) %> ago.
</span>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

Also when I update the gem to current one from the authors GitHub, even editing the gem doesnt work. Because of this I havent been able to just fork from his gem and clone it

Comment: Have you tried putting the monkey patch in an initializer? Putting it in /lib or /extras won't work.

Comment: Could you show me what to put in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module PublicActivity
 module ORM
  module ActiveRecord
   class Activity < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :micropost, foreign_key: "id", primary_key: "trackable_id"
   end
  end
 end
end
```

in `config/initializers/public_activity_monkey_patch.rb` should do it.